# How is implicit ODE different from explicit ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation); there it has been written as :

> Let F be a given function of x, y, and derivatives of y. Then an equation of the form $$F\left(x,y,y',y'',\cdots,y^{(n-1)}\right) = y^{(n)}$$ is called an explicit ordinary differential equation of order n.
>
> More generally, an implicit ordinary differential equation of order n takes the form: $$F\left(x,y,y',y'',\cdots,y^{(n-1)},y^{(n)}\right) = 0$$

Can anyone give me a good example to distinguish these two definitions; I know implicit & explicit function but having problem in visualising this here.

Comment: Explicit
$$
y'' = 2y + 6
$$
Implicit
$$
\left( y'' \right)^3 - 2y - 6 = 0
$$

Comment: @Kaster:  Why wouldn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because I think it's more a comment.

Comment: @Kaster: It's a good example.... so I thought it could be worthy to post it as an answer.

Comment: No problem :D $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit
$$
y'' = 2y + 6
$$
Implicit
$$
\left( y'' \right)^3 - 2y - 6 = 0
$$

Comment: +1; Thanks, sir. But I'm slightly confused. Can I not write the later one as explicit in the form $y'' = \sqrt[3]{2y + 6}$? Also, can there exist $x$ in the equation?? Thanks.

Comment: @user36790 Yes, you can, for this ODE. Not every implicit equation can be reduced to an explicit, or at least a single explicit equation. And yes, $x$ can be present in the equation. As a matter of fact, if you look at the definition of the both explicit and implicit equations, you can get an idea what other things might be in those equations.